# Why isn't bitcoind listening on its rpc port?

Tags: bitcoind

I run

```
sudo netstat --ip -lpa | grep bitcoin
```

After starting the bitcoin daemon and all I get is the 8333 port and the connections with other peers.

But when I do the same but with `| grep namecoin`, I get the rpc port and everything else.

I'm not being able to make `poolserverj` to work because of that.
Since it's not listening, `poolserverj` gives me a 404 response on the rpc port.

My bitcoin.conf:

```
server=1
rpcuser=xxx
rpcpassword=xxx
rpcport=8332
rpcallowip=*
gen=0
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe you should look for `bitcoind` - the Bitcoin server?

Comment: I'm using the headless version, and grep filters bitcoind with or without the "d".

Comment: I commented "rpcallowip=*" and now it's working. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce this problem with any recent versions? Looking through the code, I can't seem to find a problem in [the code where the wildcard is tested](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/util.cpp#L918).